# How to add a property into an xml?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, quartz-scheduler

I´ve a quartz-config file and I want to load my cron expression from my property file, here is the code:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<job-scheduling-data version="1.8"
    xmlns="http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/JobSchedulingData"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/JobSchedulingData http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/job_scheduling_data_1_8.xsd">
<properties>
    <property url="file:///C:/apps/Labels/resources/ftp.properties"></property>
</properties>
    <schedule>
        <job>
            <name>DevolucionesShippingJob</name>
            <group>DevolucionesShippingJob</group>
            <description>Retrieve FTP jobs procesed files from BIDS</description>
            <job-class>com.quartz.DevolucionesShippingJob</job-class>
        </job>
        <trigger>
            <cron>
                <name>DevolucionesShippingTrigger</name>
                <group>DEFAULT</group>
                <job-name>DevolucionesShippingJob</job-name>
                <job-group>DevolucionesShippingJob</job-group>
                <cron-expression>0 07 19 * * ?</cron-expression>
            </cron>
        </trigger>
    </schedule>
</job-scheduling-data>
```

The problem is that the eclipse parse marks an error in the line that has 
How can I import a property file into my xml?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: I want to import data from a properties file into my quartz-config.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since I used Quartz but I do not recall seeing this done before. Also, if I'm looking at the referenced schema correctly, the `properties` element is not valid (hence Eclipse showing an error). In short, I don't think you can do this.